# Excluding certain string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to apply regex to the below code such that I remove any string that appears between a comma and the word 'AS'.

```
Select customer_name, customer_type, COUNT(*) AS volume\nFROM table\nGROUP BY customer_name, customer_type\nORDER BY volume DESC\nLIMIT 10
```

Expected output:

```
Select customer_name, customer_type, volume\nFROM table\nGROUP BY customer_name, customer_type\nORDER BY volume DESC\nLIMIT 10
```

I tried the below but that did not give the desired output

```
result = re.sub(r",\s*COUNT\(\*\)\s*AS\s*\w+", "", text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capture group and use the group in the replacement.

```
(,\s*)[^,]*\sAS\b\s*
```

**Explanation**

- `(,\s*)` Capture group 1, match a comma and optional whitespace chars
- `[^,]*` Match any char except a comma
- `\sAS\b\s*` Match a whitespace char, then `AS` followed by optional spaces

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g0Bb4a/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Bh94tM)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"(,\s*)[^,]*\sAS\b\s*"
s = ("Select customer_name, customer_type, COUNT(*) AS volume\\nFROM table\\nGROUP BY customer_name, customer_type\\nORDER BY volume DESC\\nLIMIT 10\n")
 
print(re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s))
```

Output

```
Select customer_name, customer_type, volume\nFROM table\nGROUP BY customer_name, customer_type\nORDER BY volume DESC\nLIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks @The Fourth bird, it helped

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```py
text = "Select customer_name, customer_type, COUNT(*) AS volume\nFROM table\nGROUP BY customer_name, customer_type\nORDER BY volume DESC\nLIMIT 10"
result = re.sub(r',\s*\S+\s+AS\b\s*', ', ', text)
print(result)
```

This prints:

```
Select customer_name, customer_type, volume
FROM table
GROUP BY customer_name, customer_type
ORDER BY volume DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `,` a comma
- `\s*` optional whitespace
- `\S+` a non whitespace term
- `\s+` one or more whitespace characters
- `AS` literal "AS"
- `\b` word boundary
- `\s*` more optional whitespace